# php PDOStatement fetchAll second time

Tags: php, pdo

I do not really understand the point of PDOStatement since:

```
$PDO = new PDO(); 
$PDOS = $PDO->query($sql);

var_dump($PDOS->fetchAll()); //will return data 
var_dump($PDOS->fetchAll()); //empty
```

Is there a param that needs to be passed so that 2nd time fetchAll returns data, but without executing the SQL again?

Answer (score 1):

Just store the result the first call to `fetchAll()` into a PHP variable. Any reason you can't do that?

```
$results = $PDOS->fetchAll();
```

Then you can use `$results` as much as you need to without taxing your database any further.

Comment: Yes i know that, I was thinking that the $PDOS will not loose state after fetchAll and the result will be always available on method request.

Comment: I *think* the reason it loses state is because fetchAll() is actually requesting result rows from mysql, rather than providing you access to results it has already fetched and stored. It might work to use query buffering with mysql: http://www.php.net/pdo-mysql#pdo-mysql.constants

Answer (score 0):

The `PDOStatement` has an iterator.

`PDOStatement::fetch()` will iterate over the rowset.
When calling `fetchAll()` the iterator is at the last row.

This iterator moves only in 1 direction. The only method to go back is to execute the query again. This is the nature of the database and PHP should not keep the entire rowset in memory.